# SUM rounding decimal places 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, decimal

I have a table `EMP` that is joined with other table. In the query I used to get sum of `SAL` like this. I want this sum to be rounded to 2 decimal places, but its giving 4 decimal places. `SAL` is declared as `CHAR(9)` in `EMP` table.

```
COALESCE(CAST(SUM(CAST(SAL AS INT))/12 AS DECIMAL(13,2)), 0) as "SUM-SAL"
```

Output is showing like 29364852.000000, but I want this to be rounded to decimal places with comma separated.

Comment: Usually it is a task of your client application to format the data on the user's screen, not the task of the database.

Comment: After running your code I get only two decimal digits after comma.

Comment: It looks like you are doing an integer division , do you ever get anything but zero after the decimal point?

Comment: Why are you storing salary as `char`?

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below by using `format`

example

```
 DECLARE @test DECIMAL(18,6) = 123.456789
    SELECT FORMAT(@test, '##.##')
```

Comment: If I use format getting error Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking.

```
DECLARE @test char(9) = '29364852.00'
SELECT Format(cast(@test as decimal(10, 2)), '##,##.#0')
```

Result : 29,364,852.00

Comment: If I use format getting error Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: @SRI Please check my answer it will also run in lower version of SQL Server where format() is not available.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query.

```
DECLARE @test DECIMAL(18,6) = 123.456789
Select cast(@test as decimal(10, 2))
```

or

```
DECLARE @test char(10) = '123.456789'
Select cast(@test as decimal(10, 2))
```

[**Live Demo**](https://rextester.com/SDWK23175)

Comment: field is declared as char